# Is Foundation pollute css environment?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to make textfield with only bottom border.

ths css

```
.input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 20px;
}

    <input type="text" name="art-title" class="input"  maxlength="14" autofocus placeholder="Title"/>
```

It can worked without Foundation.

But it not worked with Foundation.

There are ways to solve it？

update:

```
    <html>

    <head>
     <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/editor.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/lib/foundation.min.css">
  </head>
        <body>
          <form>

       <input type="text" name="art-title" class="art-input"  maxlength="14" autofocus placeholder="Title"/>
    </form>
        <div class="art-container">

          <div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="art-title" class="title-input"  maxlength="14" autofocus placeholder="Title"/>
            <div class="cover-img">
              <input type="file" name="userPhoto" id="file" placeholder="Cover"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="cover-img-submit">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="editor">
            <p>sdesdssssssssssssssssss</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="/scripts/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/lib/aloha.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/editor.js"></script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

css:

```
.art-container {
    width: 57rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.title-input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
   width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 300%;
}
```

When I import Foundation css file, the textfield with only bottom borde not worked.

Comment: Your issue probably has to do with CSS Specificity. Foundation's styles are more specific than yours or you are including your styles **before** Foundation's styles.

Comment: I tried, but not worked.

Comment: You will need to supply more code. We have no idea of how you are applying your CSS and in what order etc. Saying, *"I tried, but not worked."* doesn't help us a whole lot. We cannot verify what you have done. Please include the HTML where you're including your CSS along with **all** CSS being included. You might even want to create a jsFiddle (jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Is `editor.css` where you defined all your custom styles? Like your `.input`, `.art-container` and `.title-input` CSS classes? If so, did you try swapping the order of `foundation.min.css` and `editor.css`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're running into a specificity issue. See this jsFiddle as an example, http://jsfiddle.net/fjkn9L90/. The `.title-input` class I wrote sets the height of the input to 100px. As you can see it is not 100px. Even though that class is defined after `foundation.min.css` is included in the page, `foundation.min.css` has a CSS selector that is more specific than the one I defined so the input's height is not changed to 100px. You can compare their selector `input[type="text"]` to your selector `.title-input` here: http://specificity.keegan.st/.

Comment: Even if you use a selector with higher specificity, you would still need to “remove” the other borders if a rule with lower specificity has already set them.